# Why is this statement about nowhere dense set true? How to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis

> In a metric space $X$, a subset $E$ is nowhere dense if and only if for each open set $O$ of $X$, $O \cap E$ is not dense in $O$.

Why is this statement about nowhere dense set true? How to prove it?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I couldnt figure out a starting point for this.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  Q is not nowhere dense because closure of Q is R and has nonempty interior.

Comment: Oh I see. I have confused the order of the operations. Thank you for the point out.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг you seem to know the material very well. Could you provide an answer to this question?

Comment: @user1559897 I am writing it right now, in fact. I will get back on posting it. Sorry for my earlier mistake, it was just, well, I've been awake only a few minutes.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($\implies$) Let $E$ be nowhere dense. Then, the closure of $E$ has empty interior. Now, let $O$ be any open set. We want to prove that $\overline{O \cap E} \nsupset O$. Now, first of all, note that $\overline{O \cap E} \subset \overline{O} \cap \overline{E}$. However, if $\overline{O \cap E} \supset O$, then $O \subset \overline{O} \cap \overline{E}$. Now, this means that $O \subset \overline{E}$, but then this cannot happen since $O$ has an interior point (it's non-empty) while $\overline E$ has no interior points.

($\impliedby$) Suppose that for each open set $O \subset X$, $\overline{O \cap E} \neq O$. We will argue by contradiction.

Suppose that $\overline{E}$ has an interior point, call it $y$. Then, there is an open set containing $y$, call it $U$, such that $U \subset \overline{E}$.

An easy argument shows $\overline E = E^\circ \cup \partial E$, where $\partial E$ is the boundary. Clearly, $U$ is contained inside $E^\circ$ and hence inside $E$. Therefore, $U \subset \overline{U \cap E} =  \overline U$ i.e. $U \cap E$ is dense in $U$ obviously , contradiction.

Comment: "Let E be nowhere dense. Then, the closure of E has non-empty interior." Really? Is there a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. Thank you for the point  out. Have you been able to do the part I left?

Comment: hmm couldn't figure out the part you left. Can you drop some hints?

Comment: If $A$ is contained in $B$, then the interior of $A$ is contained in the interior of $B$. Then $U$ will be contained in the interior of $\overline{E}$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I was thinking about the only if direction. Isnt $\overline{O \cap E}\neq O$ Obvious? I mean  $\overline{O \cap E}$ is closed but O is open.

Comment: U is contained in the interior of $\overline{E}$. But $U\subset \overline{U \cap E}$ is still not quite obvious to me. Can you explain? @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг?